# Loop after all elements in wordpress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, field, custom-fields

I'm using Types Fields form Toolset Plugin for Wordpress, and I've got simple custom post type with few checkoboxes. I'm rendering checked values by:

```
<?php
 $partners = types_render_field("partners", array('normal' => true));
?>

<?php echo($partners); ?>
```

output looks like this:

```
value1, value2, value3
```

The question is how can I loop after all elements in $partners, to manage this output:

```
<div class="value1"></div>
<div class="value2"></div>
<div class="value3"></div>
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with WordPress or this plugin, but if I am reading the docs correctly, I don't see an alternate function call that returns structured data (as WP sometimes supplies)  You could do something like `$p = explode(',', $partners);` then loop over `$p`.  But the Toolset API might have an in-built function for it...

Answer (score 1):

Explode your string then use php foreach short syntax :

```
$partners = explode(', ', $partners);

<?php foreach ($partners as $partner) : ?>
    <div class="<?= $parner ?>"></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I've made few corrections, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Final working version:

```
<?php $partners = explode(', ', $partners); ?>

<?php foreach ($partners as $partner) : ?>     
   <div class="<?php echo($partner) ?>"></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```